# MediaPlayer volume/other controls not working?

Tags: vb.net, media-player

I'm trying to embed a media player into my program without displaying it. I've initialized it as

```
Dim Player1 As MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer = New MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer
```

and I have a button that successfully plays the sound file I choose, but I can't change the volume/stop/mute it at all. When I printed the volume (using `Player.Volume`) it printed it as 0 even though the sound was playing at full volume. Also whenever I moused over the volume property in the debugger, it said the value was -600 and it won't let me set the volume to any number greater than 1.

```
Private Sub snd_btn_go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles snd_btn_go.Click
    Dim cue As Integer
    cue = If(Integer.TryParse(snd_txt_cue.Text, cue), Int(snd_txt_cue.Text), snd_num)
    If (cue <= dgSound.Rows.Count - 1 And cue > 0) Then
        SndCueGO(cue)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SndCueGO(cue)
    snd_num = cue
    Dim cuedata = snd_ds.Tables(0).Rows(cue - 1) 'Retrieved from a DataGridView object. 

    snd_file = cuedata.Item("file")

    If snd_file <> "" Then
        Player1.FileName = snd_file
        Player1.Play()
    Else
        MsgBox("No file was specified")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Public Property Volume As Double - The media's volume represented on a linear scale between 0 and 1. The default is 0.5.

Comment: @Plutonix I know. It doesn't change at all. I also can't stop/mute it. (using `Player1.Mute()`& `Player1.Stop()`)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have experienced the same problem:

I tried with different values and I found that the player (msdxm.tlb) doesn't work with those values, it works between -4100 and 0.

A simple player with volume control using msdxm.tlb, requires a button, a label and a trackbar:

```
 Public Class MainForm
 Dim a As New MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer
 Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Trackbar.Minimum = -41 '41+100 = 4100
    Trackbar.Maximum = 0

End Sub

Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
    Try
        a.Stop()
        a.FileName = (YOUR FILE PATH)
        a.PlayCount = 1
        a.ShowDialog(MediaPlayer.MPShowDialogConstants.mpShowDialogContextMenu)
        a.Play()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error opening file", "Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Trackbar.Scroll
    a.Volume = Trackbar.Value * 100
    VolumeLabel.Text = Math.Truncate((((a.Volume / 100) + 41) * 100 / 41)) & "%" 'shows a volume between 0% and 100% without decimals.
End Sub
End Class
```